# Firebase Storage creating repeated folders?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

In my Firebase Storage, I have a folder called **"fotoPaisesOriginais"** and, inside that folder, I have more three:

**"Europa"**

**"Ásia"**

**"Oceania"**

Each one of these folders have, in average, 50 photos inside. Everything is ok but, I didn't notice until now, every time I create a folder and put photos inside it, it creates lots of folders with the same files in the Storage Root...
This is a photo where you can see an example of it... The original folder is the first one: **"fotosPaisOriginais"**

[image]

I don't know how it creates these images. All I do with them is store their "Download Link" in my **Firebase Realtime Database**. If I open the folder "fotoPaisOriginaisOceania" it has all the files that are inside my main folder **"fotoPaisOriginais/Oceania/"**...

Comment: can you show us the code that you use to create those folders? My guess is probably you're not putting right path for those folders.

Comment: I've created the folder manually. I don't use any code to create them, just to retrieve values from the db

Comment: Then how did you put the photos there? through code?

Comment: No. I selected all the files and uploaded them to the storage.